# Twilio API For C++ ?

Tags: python, c++, twilio

Was curious if there was an implementation of the Twilio Phone Search API for C++, and if not is there a way of interfacing let's say python within C++ to get around it?

Answer (score 0):

There is no SDK for c++ . You can view the list of available libraries on their website https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries.
That said their API works over http and the sdk is just a wrapper for an http request , so you can just make the http requests directly with c++
You can view different REST calls here:

https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/available-phone-numbers?code-sample=code-find-available-local-phone-numbers&code-language=curl&code-sdk-version=json

Comment: Any examples of using that?

Comment: see modification